# Network Graph: show highly connected components

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I want to create a network graph without the small subgraphs which are disconnected from the big network graph.

Suppose I want to visualize the edgelist:

```
edgelist = {"A" -> "B", "A" -> "c", "B" -> "C",  "B" -> "D",  
  "D" -> "C",  "E" -> "F",  "G" -> "H"};
```

The network looks like

[image]

The desired output is:

[image]

As jou see, in the desired output the edges {"E" -> "F"} and  {"G" -> "H"} are  deleted. How can I do that automatically?

Comment: Look up `ConnectedComponents`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
u = UndirectedEdge @@@ edgelist;
g = First@SortBy[ConnectedComponents@Graph@u, -Length@# &]
Subgraph[Graph@edgelist, g]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Selecting the subgraph containing a specific node:

```
Subgraph[
 Graph[edgelist],
 VertexComponent[Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ edgelist], {"A"}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Why `"A"`? mmmm.. Perhaps we understood the question in a different way

Comment: @belisarius It's not clear how automatic the solution needs to be, so I decided to provide this semiautomatic alternative. If the graph can be visualized with node labels and the goal is to keep just some of the clusters, it can be done using this solution. F.e. all clusters can be selected using `{"A", "E", "G"}`, or the two small ones using `{"E", "G"}`. The nodes are arbitrary, one from each cluster that is to be kept.

Comment: Ah,ok. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 3):

In recent versions, probably the shortest way is:

```
First@WeaklyConnectedGraphComponents[edgelist]
```

[`WeaklyConnectedGraphComponents`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeaklyConnectedGraphComponents.html) orders components by size, even if the input graph is directed. `ConnectedGraphComponents` orders by size only if the graph is undirected.

Answer (score 2):

```
g =  UndirectedGraph[edgelist];
```

### ConnectedComponents

```
largecomponent = First @ ConnectedComponents[g]
```

> {"A","B","c","C","D"}

```
Subgraph[g, largecomponent , 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Medium, 
 GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"]
```

[image]

### ConnectedGraphComponents

You can also use `ConnectedGraphComponents` to get the subgraphs rather than the vertex lists corresponding to different components:

```
First[ConnectedGraphComponents[g]]
```

[image]

```
SetProperty[%, {VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  VertexSize -> Medium, GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"}]
```

[image]

### KCoreComponents

```
First[KCoreComponents[edgelist, 1]] (* or *)
First[KCoreComponents[g, 1]]
```

> {"A", "B", "c", "C", "D"}